# Android Push Notifications Ads

Tags: android, push-notification, ads

I have an app which will not be published on google play and I want to add some push notifications ads - is that possible ? Is there any mobile advertising platform which provides this for Android?

Comment: Check OneSignal SDK. Ref link : https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

Comment: @Vatsal Patel: I know One Signal - but they don't have ad notifications! They are not even a mobile advertising platform..